# How to echo a lozenge using bash?

Tags: bash, echo, unicode, rofi

I want to provide output like `zsh` powerline does:

[image: o]

My main goal is to output a lozenge indicating an active item in `rofi` which I'll be using as a dmenu. How can I echo "Active" as a lozenge the same way `zsh` does?

Comment: https://ohmybash.github.io/ might do what you want

Comment: See how it's done `echo "$PS1" | od  -bc`.